# Spark - remove special characters from rows Dataframe with different column types

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

Assuming I've a Dataframe with many columns, some are type *string* others type *int* and others type *map*.

e.g.
*field/columns `types: stringType|intType|mapType<string,int>|...`*

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  myString1      |myInt1|  myMap1                                              |...
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|"this_is_#string"| 123 |{"str11_in#map":1,"str21_in#map":2, "str31_in#map": 31}|...
|"this_is_#string"| 456 |{"str12_in#map":1,"str22_in#map":2, "str32_in#map": 32}|...
|"this_is_#string"| 789 |{"str13_in#map":1,"str23_in#map":2, "str33_in#map": 33}|...
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to remove some characters like '_' and '#' from all columns of String and Map type
so the **result** Dataframe/RDD will be:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|myString1     |myInt1|     myMap1|...                                 |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|"thisisstring"| 123 |{"str11inmap":1,"str21inmap":2, "str31inmap": 31}|...
|"thisisstring"| 456 |{"str12inmap":1,"str22inmap":2, "str32inmap": 32}|...
|"thisisstring"| 789 |{"str13inmap":1,"str23inmap":2, "str33inmap": 33}|...
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure if it's better to convert the Dataframe into an RDD and work with it or perform the work in the Dataframe.

Also, not sure how to handle the regexp with different column types in the best way (I am sing *scala*).
And I would like to perform this action for all column of these two types (string and map), trying to avoid using the column names like:

```
def cleanRows(mytabledata: DataFrame): RDD[String] = {

//this will do the work for a specific column (myString1) of type string
val oneColumn_clean = mytabledata.withColumn("myString1", regexp_replace(col("myString1"),"[_#]",""))

       ...
//return type can be RDD or Dataframe...
}
```

Is there any simple solution to perform this?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

One option is to define two udfs to handle string type column and Map type column separately:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val df = Seq(("this_is#string", 3, Map("str1_in#map" -> 3))).toDF("myString", "myInt", "myMap")
df.show
+--------------+-----+--------------------+
|      myString|myInt|               myMap|
+--------------+-----+--------------------+
|this_is#string|    3|Map(str1_in#map -...|
+--------------+-----+--------------------+
```

1) Udf to handle string type columns:

```
def remove_string: String => String = _.replaceAll("[_#]", "")
def remove_string_udf = udf(remove_string)
```

2) Udf to handle Map type columns:

```
def remove_map: Map[String, Int] => Map[String, Int] = _.map{ case (k, v) => k.replaceAll("[_#]", "") -> v }
def remove_map_udf = udf(remove_map)
```

3) Apply udfs to corresponding columns to clean it up:

```
df.withColumn("myString", remove_string_udf($"myString")).
   withColumn("myMap", remove_map_udf($"myMap")).show

+------------+-----+-------------------+
|    myString|myInt|              myMap|
+------------+-----+-------------------+
|thisisstring|    3|Map(str1inmap -> 3)|
+------------+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Psidom, may thanks for the hint. This seems to work fine, however this way, one needs to map all the columns in the Dataframe. Was looking more for a generic usage. Perhaps it's not that straight forward.. anyway Vote up, tx

Comment: Hi @Psidom, by any change is there a way to create a template function of `def remove_map:..` something like: `def remove_map[T]: Map[String, T] => Map[String, T] =` I have tried several approaches but any of them work. This wuld avoid having multiple functions, one for each combination of `Map<String, NumericField>`

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible. It might be worthwhile to ask a separate question to see if you can draw any informative answer.

Comment: Thanks, I did, but no response.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856601/scala-define-template-generic-function-to-accept-multiple-parameters